# WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token in popup window

Tags: android, dialog, popupwindow

I made custom popup dialog based on the [following link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) here my dialog. 
[image]

I have button list to show the popup. When I click these button, this dialog box will be shown. My problem is a little strange. Sometimes When I select the note edit text in dialog, I got the WindowManager$BadTokenException.

```
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@417d8d98 is not valid; is your activity running?
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:845)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:809)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(Editor.java:2147)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2104)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2349)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1647)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1546)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-06 12:34:57.878: E/AndroidRuntime(22951): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why? I didn't much change the coding. I added `mWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)` in the `popupwindow` constructor to show the dialog above the keyboard. If I run on the emulator, there is no problem. In the real device, I got exception. Is there any idea?

In the button listener I implement like this

```
 if(dialogNote == null) {
  dialogNote = new QuickActionNote(AddNewNoteActivity.this);
 }
 dialogNote.show(btn);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code used to show the dialog? In my experience this error often has been related to an activity reference leak.

Comment: My popup show without error when I click the note button. But when I click the edit text to enter data, the keyboard show below the popup and I got error.

Comment: I'm having same issue!! are you able to find any solution

Comment: This seems a bug in `PopupWindow`, the only solution worked for me is to use `Dialog`, it works exactly like `PopupWindow`

Comment: check isFinishing method before dialog show . i.e if(isFinishing()){ dialog.show();}

Answer (score 4):

This issue is because of autosuggestion enable in your phone keyboard and if you are trying to click on edit text which has prefilled data. Use android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" which will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I met the exact same problem. it seems the PopupWindow has some issue to populate the softkeyboard. the strang thing is that i can only reproduce it on Nexus10. not sure the reason now still.